# ValueError: The 'Image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, html, django

It says 'Image' attribute has no file associated what does that mean? How do I solve this issue?
I tried to search in internet and couldn't understand anything because I've only started learning.

My view:

```
def bookdata(req):
    if req.method == "POST":
        b_name = req.POST.get('book name')
        a_name = req.POST.get('author name')
        p_year = req.POST.get('published year')
        price = req.POST.get('price')
        image = req.FILE['image']
        obj = BookDetails(Name=b_name, A_Name=a_name, P_Year=p_year, Price=price, Image=image)
        obj.save()
        return redirect(add_books)
```

My model:

```
class BookDetails(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    A_Name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    P_Year = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="book images", null=True, blank=True)
```

Template:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    `<thead>`
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>A_Name</th>
        <th>P_Year</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for i in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ i.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.A_Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.P_Year }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.Price }}</td>
        <td>
            <img src="{{ i.Image.url}} ">
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

If I do it like this there is no error, but image is not shown.

```
<img src="{{ i.Image }}">
```

Comment: Maybe there is no image on storage? If you use local storage - check that specific image file exists on your disk

Comment: You are accessing `data` in the template. But are you sending `data` to this template? Or can you add the code where you are sending the `data` dictionary to the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error causes because no image is associated with the image field. Use the following code to store image properly:

```
def bookdata(req):
if req.method == "POST":
    b_name = req.POST.get('book name')
    a_name = req.POST.get('author name')
    p_year = req.POST.get('published year')
    price = req.POST.get('price')
    image = req.FILES['image']    # Change Done Here
    obj = BookDetails(Name=b_name, A_Name=a_name, P_Year=p_year, Price=price, Image=image)
    obj.save()
    return redirect(add_books)
```

In the template, you can also make some changes like :

```
<td>
    {% if i.Image %}
         <img src="{{ i.Image.url}} ">
    {% else %}
         <img src="#path_to_default_image">   
    {% endif %}
</td>
```